# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined in php script

Tags: javascript, jquery

my script is given below error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

```
<script>
     (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement; js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

view section is

```
  <blockquote cite="url">
    <a href="url"></a>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: This means that what is being returned from `d.getElementsByTagName[0]` doesn't have a property `parentNode`, because it anyway returns an **array of matching elements**. If it is a particular element that you are trying to access why don't you try out `document.getElementById()` instead?

Comment: That happens as you haven't added which tag to get in `d.getElementsByTagName[0]`  ... should be e.g. `d.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]`

Comment: what is d.getElementsByTagName[0] ? you should probably get an error in this line too. It is `document.getElementsByTagName(TagName)`

Comment: videos:108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at videos:108
    at videos:109

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `tagName` when using `getElementsByTagName()` function, thus use

```
fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
```

instead of

```
fjs = d.getElementsByTagName[0]
```

Comment: <div class="fb-video" data-href="<?php echo $url ; ?>" data-width="500" data-show-text="false">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        
      <blockquote cite="<?php echo $url ; ?>">
        <a href="url "></a>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 (function(document, s, id) {
 let js;
const id = id;
const ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

if (document.getElementById(id)) {
  return;
}

js = document.createElement('script');
js.id = id;
js.async = true;
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';

ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

[image: Facebook js]

Comment: <script>
     (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement; 
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

Comment: it is url is converted to embed facebokk url its work localy but live dosont wrk

Comment: you can see the above screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Change the version

```
<script>
 (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement; 
js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
```

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));